# How to Optimize encryption process scala

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I have written a code which first brings some ids from database and then apply encryption(AES) and then encode(JWT). Here is my code:

```
    val stdMap = result.rows.map(row => (row.values.head, row.values(1), row.values(2)))
     .groupBy(_._1)
     .mapValues(stdRow => {
       val stdName = stdRow.head._2
       val isArchived = (stdRow.head._3 != "NULL") && stdRow.head._3.toBoolean
       val value = System.currentTimeMillis()
       var encryptedStd = Util.aesEncrypt(AppConfig.secretKey, AppConfig.aesPasswordKey, stdRow.head._1)
       val encodedToken = Util.jwtEncodeString(encryptedStd)
       Map(
       "value" -> stdName.toJson,
       "isArchived" -> JsBoolean(isArchived),
       "eStdId" -> encodedToken.toJson
     )}).toJson

  def initCipher(secretKey : String, salt : String,mode : Int) : Cipher = {
   val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
   val spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256)
   val tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec)
   val skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES")
   val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
   val random = new SecureRandom()
   random.nextBytes(ivCode)
   cipher.init(mode, skeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivCode))
   cipher
 }

 def addIVToCipher(encrypted : Array[Byte]) : Array[Byte] = {
   val cipherWithIv = new Array[Byte](ivCode.length + encrypted.length)
   Array.copy(ivCode, 0, cipherWithIv, 0, ivCode.length)
   Array.copy(encrypted, 0, cipherWithIv, ivCode.length, encrypted.length)
   cipherWithIv
 }

  def aesEncrypt(secretKey: String, salt: String, value: String): String = {
    val cipher = initCipher(secretKey, salt, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE)
    val encr = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("utf-8"))
    val cipherWithIv = addIVToCipher(encr)
    Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherWithIv)
  }

  def jwtEncodeString(stdId: String): String = {
      val value = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val jwtClaim = JwtClaim(s"""{"data": "${stdId}", "time":"${value}"}""")
      Jwt.encode(jwtClaim, AppConfig.secretKey, JwtAlgorithm.HS256)
  }
```

So if i'll remove encryptedStd and encodedToken response will come in ~200-300ms But if i use encryptedStd and encodedToken response will come in ~19seconds. How to optimize this?

Answer (score 1):

Things like

```
val factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256")
val spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256)
val tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec)
val skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES")
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
val random = new SecureRandom()
```

are potentially expensive to initialize. Since you are calling it in a `.mapValues`, you might calling that several times. Actually as many times as many elements has the collection after `.groupBy`.

Reuse of `AppConfig.secretKey, AppConfig.aesPasswordKey` suggest that this is completely unneeded.

So just refactor your utils to run code of `initCither` once, by taking it out of `aesEncrypt`. Or by turning `Util` into a class that is initialized with a constructor taking values from `AppConfig`, so that for all methods cipher is already initialized and not recreated every time. This should make you pay the cost of cipher creation only once.

(Also for test purposes you could use `Random` instead of `SecureRandom` - it isn't safe but in unit tests you are not testing safety but output, so you can compute it in faster but less safer way).

Comment: All this methods(aesEncrypt, addIVToCipher, initCipher) are in object Util.scala

Comment: Then you have to refactor it into a class or write a wrapper to avoid calling `initCipher` all the time.

Comment: Before stdMap I'll get response from initCipher and addIVToCipher then pass this value to aesEncrypt?